# How do I add an event listener for clicking both mouse buttons together?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I didn't find any examples on the Internet and Vue itself supports only right and left clicks separately, which is strange because it is IMO a rather basic thing which is easy to do with plain Javascript.

I simply need a way to fire an event only when both mouse buttons are pressed, also without firing any events for the separate mouse buttons - is this possible in Vue?

Comment: _both mouse buttons are pressed_? I dont know that was a thing. Genuine question. Do you have an example of a website doing both together?

Comment: Can't you check both events with a simple double boolean statement (using mouse pressed and released events). And when both are pressed cancel the logic of the seperate buttons and start the logic for when both are pressed?

Comment: That would be my approach as well - save time left mouse button was clicked, save time right mouse button was clicked and if they are close enough do your logic.

Comment: I do not know Vue that well, is it even possible in it to tell left click from right click inside a function that was launched with v-on:click without using click.left and click.right? A silly question I suppose...

Comment: 2 aloisdg says Reinstate Monica, I need it for a simple browser game in Vue

Comment: @user3079765 alright then. For an element, it would have been a bit unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation below. "Both-Click" anywhere to test. You can adjust the timeout value for greater precision.

```js
let leftClick, rightClick;

window.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
  leftClick = event.button === 0 || leftClick;
  rightClick = event.button === 2 || rightClick;
  
  if (leftClick && rightClick) {

    // your logic here
    console.log("both clicked");

  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      leftClick = false;
      rightClick = false;
    }, 200); // <-- timeout value
  }
});


// prevent context menu
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => {
  if (leftClick && rightClick) event.preventDefault();
});
```